# Does loop condition work even it gets zero while using pointer based condition?

Tags: c, loops, pointers, data-structures, linked-list

As far my knowledge goes, a `for` loop has this structure "for(init; condition; increment)" and goes on till the condition is not zero or true. Now, I came across a code like this:

```
struct node
{
    int no;
    struct node *next;
};
struct node *first;
void creatlist()
{
    char ch='y';
    struct node *ptr,*nw;
    while(ch!='n')
    {
        printf("\nEnter item in list");
        nw=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        scanf("%d",&nw->no);
        nw->next=0;
        if(first==0)
        {
            first=nw;
        }
        else
        {
            for(ptr=first ;ptr->next!=0;ptr=ptr->next);
            {
                ptr->next=nw;
            }
        }
        printf("\nDo you want to countinue y\n");
        ch=getch();
    }
}
```

I am having some understanding problem with the for loop with "ptr->next!=0" condition as the loop is going on even though "ptr->next" is zero every time, but according to what I know, it shouldn't be. Can any one help me to find the explanation?

Comment: Trust me `ptr->next!=0` is not always `0`. That cannot be the problem. use a debugger and see what happens.

Comment: I think you should replace the zeros with `NULL`s.

Comment: Your for-loop has a trailing semicolon. Why?

Comment: "As far my knowledge goes, a loop has this structure "for(init; condition; increment)" and goes on till the condition is not zero or true." - That's one of three loop statements. And it is not clear what you mean with "till the condition is not zero or true". In C, a non-zero value evaluates to true. And the `for` loop is syntactic sugar for a `while` loop. You will find both explained in every C book. What was unclear? We are not an "explain this code I found somehere" site.

Comment: How do you know that 'ptr->next is zero'?  Your debugger?

Comment: @DavideSpataro I tried printing the value using ptr->next. every time it is printing zero.

Comment: @ForceBru Same thing happens with NULL

Comment: @Mahin: that's because most probably you added your `printf` just before `ptr->next=nw;`, ***which is already outside of the loop***. I'll repeat it here: the loop body here is the semicolon in the `for` line. That block is *not* part of the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> as the loop is going on even though "ptr->next" is zero everytime,

Not really. It's zero only for the last element of the list. That `for` loop walks the list as long as the current element has a valid `next`, so when the loop terminates `ptr` points to the last element.

At this point, we have

```
ptr->next=nw;
```

which changes the `next` pointer of the last node (currently 0) to point to the newly created node.

By the way, notice that this line is confusingly indented - it's into a block as if it was the loop body, but it's not - the `for` loop has a semicolon after it, i.e. an empty statement, which is the loop body (IOW, you have a `for` loop with an empty body, as all it has to do is already done in the increment section).

The `ptr->next=nw;` is in a block for no good reason, and it's completely independent from the loop body. That's probably the cause of your confusion if you printed the `next` value adding some `printf` here.

Comment: Thaks, I missed that :)

Comment: @Mahin also, the entire loop is stupid - rather, one just need to keep the pointer to the *last* element in the list, there is no need to reiterate each time starting from the first.